# Jquery tabs ui 1.10 tabs refresh

Tags: jquery-ui

I m using jquery tabs .Like to know how to refresh content on tab click .
I m using document ready function with 
$(#TABS).TABS()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabs").tabs();
      $("#tabs").bind("tabshow",function(event,ui){window.location.href=ui.tab;});});
```

Comment: The above is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the "select event" [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#event-select)

It says:

> This event is triggered when clicking a tab.
>   Code examples

Supply a callback function to handle the select event as an init option.

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Bind to the select event by type: tabsselect.

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks,but what i need to do for refreshing the url which is given in the href attribute

Comment: You need to write your ajax code in the $( ".selector" ).bind( "tabsselect",function(event, ui) {
  //... your ajax code to get the response and fill it in the respective div
}); I have updated the answer with a link to api documentation check that too.

Comment: Gaurav, Im not exactly sure how to do that since the two tabs have href attribute .On first page load both the tabs show the respective pages .However when i click the second time it does not load the page .Hence how to identify the tab and load its respective href URL is the question.

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery-UI 1.10, the following should help:

```
$("#TABS").tabs("load", $("#TABS").tabs("option", "active"));
```

**Edit:** More code details:

```
$(function() {
    $("#TABS").tabs();
    $("#TABS").on('click','li',function(event,ui) {
        $("#TABS").tabs("load", $("#TABS").tabs("option", "active"));
    });            
});
```

Here is a [**link to jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/xaESY/3/)

Comment: The tabs are now appaering just as list,infact lost its tab effect

Comment: @user2058240, see the full code in the updated answer. Also you can check out the jsfiddle. Note: You will have to look at the network tab to see the content refresh requests - jsfiddle will block the http requests because they're cross domain.

Comment: Thanks all,the issue was not with reload as the just by initializing Jquery UI tabs were able to reload the page .Now here is the issue.I was loading an aspx pagd which renders Jquery Highcharts .On first load it shows me the chart ,but after clicking another tab and coming back to same tab shows me a blank page .Hence i loaded another aspx page with just an aspx button in it and it worked fine .What can be the issue here